# UDP compatible packet type

Tags: sockets, udp, thermal-printer

I have a thermal printer, and the documentation on how to get the 'printer status' is as follows:

[image: Printer Documentation]

I have no idea what this means. I know how to connect to various ip address and ports (e.g. using [socket](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html)). But what does it mean to have a 'compatible packet type' and how do I send them?

Comment: https://github.com/BlackLotus/epson-stuff Here is a bit...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I remember, ENPC is a proprietary Epson protocol for device discovery / configuration. It is probably not documented publically.

If your printer supports SNMP, that's probably the easier way (most printers support the standard printer MIB), and you should be able to get status and more from it.

Comment: Some printers even support HTTP for status monitoring.